# optimize matrix multiplications

Tags: matrix-multiplication

Given:

- vectors v1, v2 (nx1) where entries in each vector are in the interval [0,1]. v1 and v2 can be sparse or dense
- a dense symmetric matrix M (nxn) (actually a logic matrix where entries are 0 or 1)
- a dense matrix E (nxn) where E(i,j) = 1-E(j,i) where E(i,j) is in the interval ]0,1[. 
  Is there a name for this type of matrix where E(i,j) = 1-E(j,i)?

I would like to compute s = Sum[(v1 * v2^T)  .* M] where .* is the element-wise multiplication operation and Sum is the sum over all entries of the resulting matrix. ^T is the transposition operation.

Given s I would like to obtain  x = Sum[(v1 * v2^T)  .* E] / s

Is there any computationally more efficient way to perform these multiplications and obtain x?

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular programming language/environment ?

Comment: Regardless of the implementation language I'd like to find if there are any shortcuts, but then probably C/C++ could be used for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.* M` multiplication is just a selection, so it could be easier to just add up the selected elements like this (in pseudocode, as you give no indication of the language):

```
sum = 0;
for i=1 to n
    for j = i to n
        if M(i,j) then
           sum += v1(i)*v2(j)+v1(j)*v2(i);
        endif
    endfor
 endfor
```

Instead of doing all 2*n^2 multiplications and n^2 additions you would only perform 2*k additions and k multiplications (where k is the number of nonzero entries of M, which is at most n^2).

For the second operation I see no way to accelerate them, so you have to compute them explicit.